# How to accepts HTTPS request instead of HTTP request in java rest controller

Tags: java, spring, https, spring-restcontroller

I tried but with generating one ssl certificate in local put into spring resource folder but its not working only http request its accepting. when i tried with https its giving something like this.

```
14:59:26.600 INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor - Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:422)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:683)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: add some code of controller...and is this full stack trace if not update with full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
you need ssl,you need token